# Should I independently version Vue.js single-file components?

Tags: vue.js, semantic-versioning

I have a sense that it would be prudent to use semver to version my components individually, seeing that the props they expect form a sort of contract. Are there any best practices in this regard? Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what your needs are.
If your components are part of one library you should version them altogether as one package.

If you are using monorepo like lerna  and publishing them as separate npm packages then it's a good idea to version them separately

Comment: What are the popular ways to achieve that?